# SQL Server MERGE syntax unknown issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I really don't know what is wrong with my procedure, does anyone understand the issue?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure merge_table_from_json, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'tgt'

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE merge_table_from_json
    (@json nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    --  Delete From dbo.ExpensesScratch;
    --  Insert Into dbo.ExpensesScratch
    --  SELECT Id, Amount, StudentName 
    --  FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    --
    --  WITH (Id uniqueidentifier,
    --        Amount real, 
    --        StudentName NVARCHAR(50))

    MERGE dbo.Expenses AS tgt 
    USING dbo.ExpensesScratch AS src ON (tgt.Id = src.Id)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET tgt.Amount = src.Amount, 
                   tgt.StudentName = src.StudentName

    WHEN NOT MATCHED by tgt THEN
        INSERT (Id, Amount, StudentName) 
        VALUES (src.Id, src.Amount, src.StudentName)

    WHEN NOT MATCHED by src THEN 
        DELETE;  

    -- OUTPUT section,
    -- DELETED.Id AS tgtId,
    -- DELETED.StudentName AS tgtSudentName.
    -- DELETED.Amount AS tgtAmount,
    -- INSERTED.Id AS srcId,
    -- INSERTED.StudentName AS srcStudentName,
    -- INSERTED.Amount AS srcAmount

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: did you try to verify your syntax against the documentation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tgt my alias was supposed to be the keyWord TARGET

Here is the completed product!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE merge_table_from_json(@json nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    Delete From dbo.ExpensesScratch;
    Insert Into dbo.ExpensesScratch
    SELECT Id, Amount, StudentName 
        FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (  Id uniqueidentifier,
            Amount real, 
            StudentName NVARCHAR(50))

MERGE dbo.Expenses t 
    USING dbo.ExpensesScratch s
ON (s.Id = t.Id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.StudentName = s.StudentName,
        t.Amount = s.Amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (Id, StudentName, Amount)
         VALUES (s.Id, s.StudentName, s.Amount)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT 
 $action,
   inserted.*,
   deleted.*;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Comment: Mark it as answer after the cutoff time, so it is helpful for others in future

Comment: @VenkataramanR will do!